# Save javascript value as plaintext in DB

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

This is the problem I get, for example, when an user inputs `<script>top.location.href=’http://www.google.nl’;</script>`
I want my application to echo it as plain text. Now, this actually works with 
htmlspecialchars()

This example works for me:

```
$test = "<script>top.location.href=’http://www.google.nl’;</script>";
echo htmlspecialchars($test);
```

But, when the user submits the form, the data goes to my DB and then returns to a 'dashboard'.
The value is now `''`.
Is there a way how I can save the data safe into my DB?

I add the values into the DB for my C# application in this way via SDK:

```
$onderwerp = htmlspecialchars(stripslashes(trim($_POST['onderwerp'])), ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8',true);
$omschrijving = htmlspecialchars(stripslashes(trim($_POST['omschrijving'])), ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8',true);

    $im = array('description' => mysql_real_escape_string($onderwerp),
                'message' => mysql_real_escape_string($omschrijving) ,
                'relation' => $_SESSION['username'],
                'messageType' => 70,
                'documentName' => $_FILES["file"]["name"],
                'documentData' => base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"])));
    $imresponse = $wcfclient->CreateInboundMessage($im);
    echo $imresponse->CreateInboundMessageResult;
```

And then call them at my dashboard in this way:

```
$roc = array('relation' => $_SESSION['username']);
$rocresponse = $wcfclient->ReadOpenCalls($roc);
foreach ($rocresponse->ReadOpenCallsResult as $key => $calls){
   echo $calls->Description;
}
```

Comment: Use PDO and you don't need to use mysql_real_escape_string ;)

Comment: That would be a great idea if the application wasn't as big as it is right now ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you please check [mysql-real-escape-string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)

**mysql_real_escape_string()** :

The mysql_real_escape_string() function escapes special characters in a string for use in an SQL statement

Also CHeck **SQL Inject** :[SQL Injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection)

Example

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
$item = "Zak's and Derick's Laptop";
$escaped_item = mysql_real_escape_string($item);
printf ("Escaped string: %s\n", $escaped_item);
?>
```

Ouput :

```
Escaped string: Zak\'s and Derick\'s Laptop
```

Comment: I use mysql_real_escape_string, but still the value is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, read about [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php).

Comment: Then show your code how do you save values to database and select them ad dashboard.